# Adding 4 values in 4 textboxes and displaying the sum in the 5th textboxes

Tags: c#

I want to display my total to the last textbox where named "txttotal" and this code didn't work. Is there any syntaxes was wrong? Sorry for my grammar.

```
    private void txttotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Int32 val1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtquiz.Text);
       Int32 val2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtpart.Text);
       Int32 val3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtmexam.Text);
        Int32 val4 = Convert.ToInt32(txtfexam.Text);
       Int32 val5 = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
       txttotal.Text = Convert.ToString(val5); 


    }
```

Comment: why you are doing this on "txttotal_TextChanged" event. either do it on all four text box change event or write it on some button click

Comment: *didn't work* is a very broad observation. Please be specific. Did you get any exception ? Wrong calculation ? Did you debug this code ? And you need to hook this event to all textboxes expect the total (which is the opposite of what you're doing)

Comment: When you say "this code didn't work", do you mean that there was an error somewhere? If so could you post it? If not, are you sure the event "txtTotal_TextChanged" gets triggered? Have you set a breakpoint there?

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see is that txttotal_TextChanged is the event for text box that you want to display the total. It will be tricky since how will you trigger this event. My suggestion is use button to trigger click event. if still you want to use TextChanged event then create TextChanged for txtquiz,txtpart,txtmexam,txtfexam which is repetitive and not advisable to do.

Answer (score 0):

As K D suggested don't use txttotals `TextChanged` event. Also `Convert.ToInt32()` function will throw an exception with empty strings so keep that in mind when getting values from all text boxes in one `TextChanged` function (once you write in the first TextBox others will still be empty when TextChanged triggers).
You could for example set variables to 0 first and then use `int.TryParse` function.

```
int val1 = 0;    
int.TryParse(txtquiz.Text, out val1);
```

EDIT:
So to update a little bit, you could make one TextChanged event and assign it to your 4 textboxes (not txttotal)

```
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 val1, val2, val3, val4;
    Int32.TryParse(txtquiz.Text, out val1);
    Int32.TryParse(txtpart.Text, out val2);
    Int32.TryParse(txtmexam.Text, out val3);
    Int32.TryParse(txtfexam.Text, out val4);
    Int32 val5 = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
    txttotal.Text = Convert.ToString(val5);
}
```